# Flutter ViewModel old data is repopulating (using Provider)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter-provider

I'm using multiProvider to manage state in flutter. The main problem that i'm facing is;
Unable to clear the data inside my viewModel after closing a page. When i open the page again, old data is populating from viewModel.

Because of this issue i've created a 'reset' method in my viewModel & calling this 'reset' method before open the page.

Is there any way to remove old values from viewModel :- Please suggest

My code:

**Main Page**
Adding providers under multi provider

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ViewModel1()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ViewModel2()),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
          ),
          //Set Home Page after splash
          home: HomePage(),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my Homepage**  Navigate to FirstPage & reset ViewModel1 data

```
 HomePage()
   {
   :
   :
   :
   onPressed(){
     Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()));
     Provider.of<ViewModel1>(context, listen: false).reset();
              }
  }
```

This is My Page:

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ViewModel1 _viewModel1 =
    Provider.of<ViewModel1>(context, listen: true);

    TextFormField(
      controller: _fNameController,
      onChanged: _viewModel1.setFname,
    );
  }
}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel1 with ChangeNotifier {
  String _fName = '';

  String get fName => _fName;

  setFname(String fName) {
    _fName = fName;
    notifyListeners();
    setFnameValidation(fName
        .trim()
        .isNotEmpty ? true : false);
  }

  //TODO Reset all values
  void reset() {
    _fName = '';
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are reusing one model on different pages, without sharing data between pages.. It's better to create and close the model on every page.

Comment: Hi Kherel. Thanks for the Answer.
If you are creating a ViewModel on every page (build method),
How to bind a TextEditing controller with view Model in initState() 
I think; For this we have to create a separate instance of 'ViewModel1'
Eg:
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        ),

        body: ChangeNotifierProvider< ViewModel1 >(
          create: (BuildContext context) => viewModel,
          child: Consumer< ViewModel1 >(builder: (context, viewModel, _) {
            return Container()